# Hiding IP Address/Geo Location Spoofing, VPN, Proxy, Proxy DNS or something else?

Tags: vpn, dns, proxy

Let me explain the scenario.

**I am in country B, I have a subscription to the software that must be used while residing within Country A. In case of violation they will ban my subscription forever.**

> The software is a mix of desktop application which uses web-services to communicate with their servers and web portal supposed to be open in chrome or IE. My only target is to spoof my location such that either through IP Address (desktop application scenario) or through browser location sharing it is impossible to detect the correct location without letting them (software vendor) know that I am spoofing my location.

Can someone put light on how to achieve above-mentioned target?

- I was looking into VPN (Like ExpressVPN) to hide the IP and spoof the geo-location. ExpressVPN live chat agent was honest enough to inform me that hiding IP and geo-location spoofing will work successfully but someone (on their servers) who is receiving the request will know that you are using VPN which will result in banning my subscription (It will be a great loss).
- Then I moved to looking into proxy SmartProxy live chat agent told me that our problem will be solved successfully using proxy. There are still 2 problems with SmartProxy

  1- They are very costly (probably because of residential ips)

  2- They told me that if someone open the web browser and allow a website to get the location Geo-Location spoofing will not work in this case rather website will be able to get the original location. Their spoofing will work in a case where websites look into the IP Address for detecting geo-location.

I am new to this domain (vpn-proxy-dns), please guide me if something is wrong with the post or **if the forum is incorrect, then please guide me to correct forum**. Am I missing something that will be helpful to get the guidance quickly?

> I am short on time (2-3 days available) that's why I am open to paid (cheap) solution as well.

Comment: TeamViewer to your home computer. Anything else runs the risk of being spotted.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin for response but TeamViewer is not an option for me.